# HIde popup when clicked on JFrame header

Tags: java, swing, events

I have JFrame and JTextField on it.

I create a popup window based on JWindow, it show when textField has invalid value.

I want to hide my popup when main JFrame is moved or when i click on JFrame header.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `WindowFocusListener` to the `JWindow`, and `setVisible(false)` when the window loses focus. Something like this:

```
  popup.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
         if (popup.isVisible()){
             popup.setVisible(false);
         }
      }
  });
```

Or if that's not what you're after, you can add a `ComponentListener` to your `JFrame`:

```
  frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){

     public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
         if (popup.isVisible()){
             popup.setVisible(false);
         }
      }
  });
```

Comment: JWindow doesn't receive focus. And componendMoved occurs only when moving is finished and don't work when we move window and press [ESC]

Comment: Consider then an `undecorated JDialog`.

Comment: i don't wont to lose a focus from TextField )